# How to suppress variable type within value attribute using ng-options?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Running AngularJS 1.4.0-rc.1 the value within a `ng-options` loop contains the type of the variable.

See the following code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.1/angular.js">
</script>
<script>
  angular.module("selectOptionsTest", []).
    controller("SelectOptionsController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
      $scope.options = [
        {id: 1, label: "Item 1"},
        {id: 2, label: "Item 2"},
        {id: 3, label: "Item 3"}
      ];
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="selectOptionsTest" ng-controller="SelectOptionsController">
  <select ng-model="opt" ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in options">
  </select>
</div>
```

This generates HTML code which looks like this:

```
<select ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in options" ng-model="option" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
  <option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="number:1" label="Item 1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="number:2" label="Item 2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="number:3" label="Item 3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Why is the value prefixed by the type of the variable, i.e. `number:`? In previous versions of AngularJS (e.g. the current stable 1.3.15) the `value` attributes are filled with the expected values of `1`, `2` and `3`.

So is this a bug in 1.4.0-rc.1 or do those cases need to be handled differently now?

Comment: I'ts listed in the breaking changes for ngOptions. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef

Comment: Thank you @Claies. That clarifies what has changed exactly.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Obviously there was a change in how the `ngOptions` directive is handled. This change is briefly explained in the [migration notes for AngularJS 1.4](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#ngoptions). A more detailed description of the changes can be found in the [commit message](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef):

> When using `ngOptions`: the directive applies a surrogate key as the
>   value of the `<option>` element. This commit changes the actual string
>   used as the surrogate key. We now store a string that is computed by
>   calling `hashKey` on the item in the options collection; previously it
>   was the index or key of the item in the collection.
>
> (This is in keeping with the way that the unknown option value is
>   represented in the select directive.)
>
> Before you might have seen:
>
> `<select ng-model="x" ng-option="i in items">
>    <option value="1">a</option>
>    <option value="2">b</option>
>    <option value="3">c</option>
>    <option value="4">d</option>
>   </select>`
>
> Now it will be something like:
>
> `<select ng-model="x" ng-option="i in items">
>    <option value="string:a">a</option>
>    <option value="string:b">b</option> 
>    <option value="string:c">c</option>
>    <option value="string:d">d</option>
>   </select>`
>
> If your application code relied on this value, which it shouldn't,
>   then you will need to modify your application to accommodate this. You
>   may find that you can use the `track by` feaure of `ngOptions` as this
>   provides the ability to specify the key that is stored.

This means that you now need to use `track by` to get the same result as before. To fix the example in the question it needs to look like this then:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js">
</script>
<script>
  angular.module("selectOptionsTest", []).
    controller("SelectOptionsController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
      $scope.options = [
        {id: 1, label: "Item 1"},
        {id: 2, label: "Item 2"},
        {id: 3, label: "Item 3"}
      ];
    }]);
</script>
<div ng-app="selectOptionsTest" ng-controller="SelectOptionsController">
  <select ng-model="opt" ng-options="option.id as option.label for option in options track by option.id">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: As a note: you should use `select as` together with `track by` with caution since they can cause trouble. See here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions and an example here https://jsbin.com/fadavamacu/1/edit?html,js,output (try to select multiple values, you will note that Angular recognizes them but the visible selection will be lost)

Comment: Adding `track by` also adds empty option in the beginning.

Comment: @Karmo Rosental No, ngModel adds an option when value is not found in options.

Answer (score 1):

See [migration guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration) for kind of obscure explanation of this breaking change, under the **ngOptions** heading.

> Due to [7fda214c](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef), when ngOptions renders the option values within the
>   DOM, the resulting HTML code is different. Normally this should not
>   affect your application at all, however, if your code relies on
>   inspecting the value property of  elements (that ngOptions
>   generates) then be sure to [read the details](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/7fda214c4f65a6a06b25cf5d5aff013a364e9cef).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When linking to an external guide it's also nice to put an excerpt from the part you are referencing.