# Misunderstanding with ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Well I'm seriously confused by ng-options. Why make it so difficult??

Anyway, maybe you good folks can help lift the fog...

I have an array of currencies:

```
["gbp", "usd", "eur"];
```

etc stored in:

```
$scope.providedCurrencies
```

I am trying to access them and display them 'The Angular Way' with ng-options in a Select menu, like so:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCurrency"
        ng-options="currency for currency in providedCurrencies"
        ng-init="selectedCurrency=gbp">
</select>
```

This will then update a series of payment options to display the different monetary values, based on the currency selected.

**The problems:**

The format for writing the ng-options doesn't make a lot of sense to me, even after the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) and various tutorials :(

Also even with the ng-init (from a tutorial) the Select menu will set an empty value on page load. This is then removed when the user selects a different value.

Additionally the value of each option in the DOM is `"string:gbp"`.

There seems to be more information around when dealing with data in objects over arrays. Should I do that? Even though the docs show options for arrays?

Please help :)

Comment: lol is 'hell' not allowed in a title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were forget to do single quote only:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCurrency"
    ng-options="currency for currency in providedCurrencies"
    ng-init="selectedCurrency='gbp'">
</select>
```

Check this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RrNyvb

Comment: Thank you, this does indeed sort the default value showing correctly, so that's excellent. However the DOM values are still showing as "string:gbp". Is there any way around this?

The codepen looks good, but this uses ng-repeat into a table?

Comment: @DanHodson  I see no table in the codepen OR your question.  Perhaps another question with that in there?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you are indeed correct, the link I went to must've been cached or something as it was a completely different pen. The provided Pen is correct and shows the value="gbp", so I'm not sure what's wrong with mine...

Comment: Ok It's all fixed and @Arvaan can have the solution, so thanks to all who replied. The issue with the `value="string:gbp"` is fixed by including `track by currency` in the ng-options. The SO post that helped me fixed this can be [found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120230/how-to-suppress-variable-type-within-value-attribute-using-ng-options)