# ngOptions using basic expression providing odd rendered value

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I have the following `Object` in `TypeScript` defining some options for a `<select>` using `ng-options`:

```
$scope.sOptions = [
   {
      name: "Female"
   }, 
   {
      name: "Male"
   }];
```

I provide the following for `ng-options` to `AngularJS`:

`ng-options="opt.name for opt in sOptions"`

This actually works except for the fact that according to the documentation for `ng-option`, the `value` should just be the loop counter while building out the `<option>` elements. However I see the following rendered:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
<option label="Female" value="object:6">Female</option>
<option label="Male" value="object:7">Male</option>
```

What I'm expecting to see is something like the following:

```
<option value="0" selected="selected"></option>
<option label="Female" value="1">Female</option>
<option label="Male" value="2">Male</option>
```

What am I doing incorrectly to have those odd values being produced for the `value` of the `<option>` element?

**EDIT:** After reading the correct answer provided, this other post goes into detail about a similar issue and also how to use `track by` for this requirement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30292209/410937

Comment: this is happening because your select list is an array of objects rather than an array of primitives.  There are some ways around this issue, but the most direct route would be to supply an array of strings, unless you need other values in this object that you aren't showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this requirement you have to use `track by` in `ng-select`. The track by will help you in binding the select option with a value tag. You should also provide an Unique Id field to track the select option.

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.Name for item in names track by item.Id">
</select>
```

In your controller the names object will be like this

```
$scope.names = [{Name: "Name1", Id: 0}, {Name: "Name2", Id: 1}, {Name: "Name3", Id: 2}];
```

In order to initialize the select option you can set the model by

```
$scope.selectedName = $scope.names[0];
```

You can initialize the scope variable only if you use the track by property in select option

Comment: This did it! Using `track by` and having an `id` on the collection per element, resulted in the desired outcome: `<option label="Female" value="1">Female</option>`

Comment: Yes, Using track by is the method suggested by Angular for ng-select. Thats the best practice too

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you haven't used an `ng-model` in your select attribute. Angular does this to prevent model select by accident. You need to bind your select and the "empty" option will go away.

```
<select ng-options="opt.name for opt in sOptions"
    ng-model="someScopeVar">
</select>
```

Comment: seems right at first blush, but `ng-options` won't generate a list at all without an `ng-model`.  also, the question isn't with the `?` value, it's with the `object:6` values instead of `1`.

Comment: Yes unfortunately this was not the answer or have any bearing on the rendered outcome. I didn't have it in my OP, but the `ng-model` attribute was already defined.